# Xamarin forms - Remove burger menu icon but keep nav bar

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image: Remove burger icon]

I'm wanting to remove the burger menu icon whilst retaining the navigation bar. I want to add content to the `NavigationPage.TitleView` property and i would like it to take the full width of the page. In the image i've attached, the yellow background colour shows the width that the `TitleView` is currently occupying.

I know in forms you can control the visibility of the back button, is there a way you can also control the burger menu icon? Based on what i've been reading, this will most likely require a custom renderer, which i've tried with no luck. I need to support iOS & Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, at the moment, this is not possible. You can hide the burger menu but it still takes up space (see Leon Lu's answer).

My solution was to create a custom navigation bar, that way i have full control. If you want to do this first remove the navigation bar:

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

Then add your custom nav using regular xaml code, just like you would with any other component.

One to thing to keep in mind is that in ios your nav can show where the notch is, to fix this you need to use this code:

`On<iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);`

Answer (score 0):

In the android, you can use following custom renderer code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Graphics.Drawable;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MesterDetailspage.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MasterDetailPage), typeof(MyMasterDetailRenderer))]
namespace MesterDetailspage.Droid
{
    public class MyMasterDetailRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {

        public MyMasterDetailRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as Android.Widget.ImageButton;
                    var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
                    if (drawerArrow == null)
                        continue;
                    bool displayBack = false;
                    var app = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current;
                    var detailPage = (app.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail;
                    var navPageLevel = detailPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count;
                    if (navPageLevel > 1)
                        displayBack = true;
                    if (!displayBack)
                        ChangeIcon(imageButton, Resource.Drawable.test1);
                    if (displayBack) ;
                        //ChangeIcon(imageButton, Resource.Drawable.back1);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ChangeIcon(Android.Widget.ImageButton imageButton, int id)
        {
            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Context.GetDrawable(id));
            imageButton.SetImageResource(id);
        }
    }
}
```

I set a transparent background image.

[image]

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

For iOS, just set the `IconImageSource="test1.png"` in `MasterDetailPage` tag in xamarin forms xaml.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            IconImageSource="test1.png"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MesterDetailspage.Views"
            x:Class="MesterDetailspage.Views.MainPage">
```

Comment: Hi @Leon Lu - MSFT , thanks for providing an answer. This approach only conceals the burger menu (doesn't actually remove it, because it still takes up space). I've updated the question to be more specific, could you please read it again and let me know if you have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @Shoaybsh Based on your description, remove the all the nav bar, then create a `StackLayout` as a navi bar, put it at the postion of nav bar, you can add what ever you want, the `StackLayout` will take the full width of the page. If you do not remove the nav bar. we have to rewrite the nav bar layout in custom renderer for taking the full width of the page.

Comment: I'm open to rewriting the nav bar layout to take full width. Do you have any examples of this? I prefer this approach.

Comment: You can add a `VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"` for your `StackLayout` as the  nav bar like this screenshot.  https://imgur.com/a/ZuLdBAJ